# Python 3.6 Pandas Select all row from some columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Have a dataframe like this:

```
a   b   c   d
1   1   Nan 1
Nan 2   Nan 2  
Nan 3   Nan 3
4   4   4   Nan
```

I need to get all rows containing "Nan" from all columns except "с" while column "с" is still visible, so its contents are also important. In other words, the output should be like this:

```
a   b   c   d
Nan 2   Nan 2
Nan 3   Nan 3
4   4   4   Nan
```

I was able to do this by selectively replacing the Nan values ​​from the "a, b, d" columns with "value 1" and the values ​​of the "c" column with "value 2", thereby being able to filter as I would like. But a real table contains about 16 billion values, so I think my way is not the best way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `loc` with `drop`, `isna` and `any`:

```
df.loc[df.drop('c', axis=1).isna().any(1)]
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c    d
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `isna()` on the dataframe for the columns you want to check if `NaN` exists in the row, then call `any` on `axis=1`, finally use this mask to get the required dataframe:

```py
>>> df[df[[c for c in df if c!='c']].isna().any(axis=1)]

     a    b    c    d
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0
3  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

you can exlcude `c` from your target columns and return the index of your target columns.

```
idx = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('c')].isna().any(1)

df.loc[idx]


     a  b    c    d
1  NaN  2  NaN    2
2  NaN  3  NaN    3
3    4  4    4  NaN
```